# Finding ips and hosts in a LAN . Different results

Tags: ip, nmap, ipconfig

I need to scan a LAN and match hosts with ips. I used nmap -sL 192.168.1.*   and i got a list of hosts and ips as i wanted. But when i checked using ipconfig on a few machines i saw that resuts form ipconfig were different. for example host with name acer2 had ip 192.168.1.200 according to nmap and 192.168.1.25 according to ipconfig. Is that even possible? Did i do something wrong? I am really confused.

Thank you all. I hope i posted the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved hostnames can lie if DNS isn't consistent or hosts files are partially in effect. IP to MAC address should remain consistent however.

On the machine you run nmap on, try also doing an nslookup on the IP and see if the hostname stays matching up. If so, check your DNS/WINS/HOSTS file entries to be sure they are all consistent.

`nmap -sL` is simply listing IP addresses, and then reverse-dns querying each IP to it's default nameserver, it doesn't actually reach-out to the clients themselves.